# Требования к или по?

Tags: грамматика

Как правильно в технической документации писать о технических требованиях, предъявляемых к изделию?
Например, речь идет о надежности, жесткости, живучести изделия. 
Должно быть "требования к надежности" или "требования по жесткости" (потому что требования К изделию ПО критерию жесткости) или вообще "требования живучести" (без предлога)?

Answer (score 0):

Взгляд на подборку в НКРЯ указывает, что «требования к надежности» (машин) — довольно стандартная форма записи в технической документации: *требования к надежности страховой защиты; требования к частотным характеристикам; требования к точности регулирования; требования к будущей системе; требования к используемым имитационным моделям*.

Предлог ***по*** скорее приложим к общим понятиям — областям знаний, сферам деятельности. Примеры из корпуса: *требования по кредитам; требования по росту тарифов; требования по безопасности; требования по каждому направлению; требования по охране окружающей среды.*

Answer (score 0):

***Требования к жесткости, к живучести***
Если речь идет о каком-то объекте или его свойстве, то только так.
К примеру, взять хотя бы названия ГОСТов, то там в подобных случаях только такое управление.

В профессиональной речи, впрочем, возникают и другие варианты управления, не слишком пригодные к использованию в документах.

Например, *"Требования на"* нежелательно использовать в документации, поскольку возможна двусмысленность: "требование на" - это документ бухгалтерского и складского учета.

*"Требования по"* возможно только в значении "в соответствии с чем", "согласно чему": *требования по документу такому-то*.

Беспредложный вариант (*требование чего-то*) в данном контексте тоже сомнителен по тем же причинам, так как в первую очередь применяется для указания источника требований.

(+) =====
Возможны варианты типа "задание требований по надежности" или "требования по обеспечению безопасности". Я их выношу за скобки, это другой контекст.